# Embedding a Web page in an Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-emulator, html

I am trying to embed a webpage inside an android app.
Following is the code written in the main_activity java file of my app.

```
package com.example.webpage;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever i launched my app in an emulator it shows me the "Page not Found" error.
Please help me out.
[image: Output in the emulator]

Comment: try this `https://www.google.com`

Comment: have you set <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your manifest?

Comment: Thanks to **Moradiya Akash** and **M D**. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. First, you take the webview in XML.
2. Bind to them like:

   ```
   WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   ```
3. Then do this:

   ```
   String url = "http://www.google.com/";
   WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl(url);
   ```